# JBehave - Ignoring failures in examples

Tags: jbehave

I have many scenarios with Examples. In case of failure for an "Example", JBehave stop executing the scenario for remaining list of examples. e.g.

Given a record with classification 
When I view the page
Then I see the record has type

Examples:
|classification|type|
|classification_1|type_1|
|classification_2|type_2|
|classification_3|type_3|
|classification_4|type_4|

If the scenario fails for

|classification_2|type_2|

then it will not execute 3 and 4.
Is there a way to configure JBehave to execute all the examples even in cas of failures?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging with JBehave source code, looks like it is not possible. In StoryRunner class, in case of failure it uses instance of "`SomethingHappened implements State`" which doesn't look at any strategy just does the following:

```
StepResult result = step.doNotPerform(scenarioFailure);
result.describeTo(reporter.get());
```

Hence we see step NOT PERFORMED in the report.

I wish I'm wrong and somebody more knowledgeable can correct me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be similar to a post I have just answered.  Please check your configuration.  More information can be found here

[JBehave : How to ignore failure in scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192539/how-do-i-make-jbehave-ignore-failed-scenarios?rq=1)