# Run succeeding steps in Jbehave story when preceding step failed

Tags: bdd, jbehave

I have the following script output:

```
Scenario: Continue after failed assert

Given value is 1
When value is added 1
Then new value is 2 (FAILED)
(java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<2> but was:<3>)
Then run after failed assert (NOT PERFORMED)
```

Is it possible to make the step marked as "NOT PERFORMED" still run even though the previous step failed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to run other stories if a single step fails (see [Ignoring failures in stories](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/running-stories.html) section).  However most of the tests I've written with JBehave depend on the app being in a proper state.  So having the entire story fail as a result of a failing step is necessary since I can't really predict what state the system will be in if any step fails unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it possible to run the extra steps in that specific example.  If you have other Scenarios after that you would like to run, irrespective of previous failures, then follow the steps in the answer to the post below.

[JBehave : How to ignore failure in scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192539/how-do-i-make-jbehave-ignore-failed-scenarios?rq=1)