# Jbehave maven - Run all the scenarios although some fail

Tags: java, maven, jbehave

I'm running Jbehave maven plugin with run-stories-with-annotated-embedder. But when any scenario fails, then stop all the other scenarios. But **I would like to run all the scenarios and then do a report with the scenarios that fails**. Is it possible to do this ??

I setup the jbehave strategy configuration to SilentlyAbsorbingFailure, and also I tryed ignoreFailureInStories option... but it dosen't work for me. I think I am missing something.

This is my maven execution code when fails:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Consumer Regression Test Suite .................... SUCCESS [0.591s]
[INFO] Customer Regression Test Suite Commons module ..... SUCCESS [2.678s]
[INFO] Customer Regression Test Suite Core module ........ FAILURE [25:24.539s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25:28.081s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 16 15:42:02 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 71M/664M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:3.7.4:run-stories-with-    annotated-embedder (embeddable-stories) on project consumer-regression-test-suite-core:     Failed to run stories with annotated embedder runner: Annotated embedder run failed with    runner org.jbehave.core.junit.spring.SpringAnnotatedEmbedderRunner@72f4abb9: Failures in   running stories:        ReportsCount[stories=2,storiesNotAllowed=0,storiesPending=0,scenarios=16,scenariosFailed=2,     scenariosNotAllowed=0,scenariosPending=0,stepsFailed=2] -> [Help 1]
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal     org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:3.7.4:run-stories-with-annotated-embedder (embeddable-     stories) on project consumer-regression-test-suite-core: Failed to run stories with    annotated embedder runner
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run stories with    annotated embedder runner
    at org.jbehave.mojo.RunStoriesWithAnnotatedEmbedderRunner.execute(RunStoriesWithAnnotatedEmbedderRunner.java:23)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
 Caused by: org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$AnnotatedEmbedderRunFailed: Annotated    embedder run failed with runner org.jbehave.core.junit.spring.SpringAnnotatedEmbedderRunner@72f4abb9
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesWithAnnotatedEmbedderRunner(Embedder.java:178)
    at org.jbehave.mojo.RunStoriesWithAnnotatedEmbedderRunner.execute(RunStoriesWithAnnotatedEmbedderRunner.java:21)
    ... 21 more
 Caused by: org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$RunningStoriesFailed: Failures in running stories: ReportsCount[stories=2,storiesNotAllowed=0,storiesPending=0,scenarios=16,scenariosFailed=2,scenariosNotAllowed=0,scenariosPending=0,stepsFailed=2]
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$ThrowingRunningStoriesFailed.handleFailures(Embedder.java:499)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.handleFailures(Embedder.java:265)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.generateReportsView(Embedder.java:252)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.generateReportsView(Embedder.java:233)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:212)
    at nl.tele2.crts.core.business.configuration.CommonsStoryConfiguration.run(CommonsStoryConfiguration.java:89)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesWithAnnotatedEmbedderRunner(Embedder.java:173)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the   following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :consumer-regression-test-suite-core
```

My Maven configuration:

```
...

    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jbehave.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-view-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-view-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>embeddable-stories</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                        <includes>
                                  <include>**/Order1Story.java</include>
                                  <include>**/Order2Story.java</include>
                                  <include>**/Order3Story.java</include>
                                  <include>**/Order4Story.java</include>
                                    </includes>
                        <generateViewAfterStories>true</generateViewAfterStories>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run-stories-with-annotated-embedder</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.16</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

My Story class:

```
@RunWith(SpringAnnotatedEmbedderRunner.class)
@Configure()
@UsingEmbedder(embedder = Embedder.class, generateViewAfterStories = true,     ignoreFailureInStories = false, ignoreFailureInView = false, storyTimeoutInSecs = 1200)
@UsingSpring(resources = { "classpath:crts-application-context.xml",
                          "classpath:steps/dsl/crts-jbehave-commons-dsl-configuration-    steps.xml",
                          "classpath:steps/dsl/crts-jbehave-order-dsl-steps-    context.xml" })
public class Order1Story extends CommonsStoryConfiguration {

protected List<String> storyPaths() {
    return new     StoryFinder().findPaths(codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()).getFile(),
            asList("**/" + System.getProperty("storyFilter", "*") + "order/dsl/order-  1P-dsl*.story"), null);
   }

}
```

Configuration class:

```
public abstract class CommonsStoryConfiguration extends InjectableEmbedder {

@Test
public void run() throws Throwable {

    final CrossReference crossReference =
            new   CrossReference().withJsonOnly().withOutputAfterEachStory(true).excludingStoriesWithNoExecutedScenarios(true);

    final SeleniumContext seleniumContext = new SeleniumContext();

    // Step Monitor
    // final ContextView contextView = new LocalFrameContextView().sized(640, 120);
    // final SeleniumStepMonitor stepMonitor = new SeleniumStepMonitor(contextView,
    // seleniumContext, crossReference.getStepMonitor());

    // Formatting
    final Format[] formats = new Format[] { new SeleniumContextOutput(seleniumContext), CONSOLE, HTML };

    // StoryRporterBuilder
    final StoryReporterBuilder reporterBuilder = new StoryReporterBuilder();
    reporterBuilder.withCodeLocation(codeLocationFromClass(CommonsStoryConfiguration.class));
    reporterBuilder.withFailureTrace(true);
    reporterBuilder.withFailureTraceCompression(true);
    reporterBuilder.withDefaultFormats();
    reporterBuilder.withFormats(formats);
    reporterBuilder.withCrossReference(crossReference);

    // PatternParser
    final RegexPrefixCapturingPatternParser stepPatternParser = new RegexPrefixCapturingPatternParser("$");

    // Parameter converter
    final DateConverter dateConverter = new DateConverter(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    final ParameterConverters parameterConverters = new ParameterConverters();
    parameterConverters.addConverters(dateConverter);

    // Failure Strategy
    final FailureStrategy strategy = new SilentlyAbsorbingFailure();

    // Story Control
    final StoryControls storyControls = new StoryControls();
    storyControls.doDryRun(false);
    storyControls.doSkipScenariosAfterFailure(false);

    // Configuration
    final Configuration configuration = injectedEmbedder().configuration();
    configuration.useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(CommonsStoryConfiguration.class));
    configuration.useStoryReporterBuilder(reporterBuilder);
    configuration.useStepPatternParser(stepPatternParser);
    configuration.useParameterConverters(parameterConverters);
    configuration.useFailureStrategy(strategy);
    configuration.useStoryControls(storyControls);
    // configuration.useStepMonitor(stepMonitor);

    injectedEmbedder().runStoriesAsPaths(storyPaths());

}

protected abstract List<String> storyPaths();

}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes you can, but you have to code it, I have like 1000 test cases defined on test-rail which are executed without taking into account if the previous was Ok or no, if it fails the application prints a screenshot and uploads on test-rail test-case.

Comment: Nice! How do you do to not stop the test execution ? any extraconfiguration in Java, in maven ? 

Thanks in advance,

Comment: programatically, you have to iterate over each test-case

Comment: Do you have an example ?

Comment: not that I can share but it is a simple for loop

Comment: do you itereate every story file ? in the storypaths ?

Comment: I said I use jbehave with testrail (http://www.gurock.com/testrail/) so I iterate over every test case, yes, so I can determine if that test-case works well or failed

Comment: ah! ok, thanks! Well I'm not using testrail. But I think I find the solution just catching the exception in the run method, and allow the test to continue running:

    `try {
    
                injectedEmbedder().runStoriesAsPaths(storyPaths());
    
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("There were errors in the Story, but we want to continue with the other ones");
            }`

Comment: it is important then to LOG what story caused the error to be able to solve it.

Comment: Well, I can see all the stories that fail in the final report. 

But I don't like it at all, if something fail.. then the build would be green and should be yellow in Jenkins... any idea to throw an exception that can continue with the next story but mark the build as unstable ?

Comment: We do that part between jenkins and testrail, so I cannot help here sorry

Comment: I know, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

For continue running scenarios, set

ignoreFailureInStories=true

See [How do I make JBehave ignore failed scenarios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192539/how-do-i-make-jbehave-ignore-failed-scenarios)

Comment: How we will use "ignoreFailureInStories=true"?

Comment: Did you try jvm parameter -DignoreFailureInStories=true